# In R, what is the function of 'waiver()'?

Tags: r, data-visualization, visualization, graph-visualization

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, size = hwy)) +
  geom_point()
p + scale_size(
  name = waiver(),
  breaks = waiver(),
  labels = waiver(),
  limits = NULL,
  range = c(1, 10),
  trans = "identity",
  guide = "legend"
)
```

In the above code what does 'waiver()' means and what it function?

Comment: From the online doc (always a good place to look: did you try there?): "A waiver is a "flag" object, similar to NULL, that indicates the calling function should just use the default value. It is used in certain functions to distinguish between displaying nothing (NULL) and displaying a default value calculated elsewhere (waiver())"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up the documentation for waiver by typing `?waiver` into the R console. The `scale_size` documentation also describes its purpose in your use case.

In sum, `waiver()` specifies that a function should use a default value as a particular argument.

So, in your example, if `name = waiver()`, the name of the scale is taken from the first mapping used for that aesthetic. Likewise if `breaks = waiver()` or `labels = waiver()`, default breaks and labels are used by the function.